# Objects passed as parameters have no methods

Tags: javascript, object, parameters

I am trying to have the server create an object and pass it to the client. If the object contains simple attributes, this works fine, but when the object contains functions, the client cannot access them.

Below is a sample of my code:

```
exports.mapObject = function(x, y, spriteName)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = 0;
    this.spriteName = spriteName;

    this.initialize = function()
    {
        console.log("hi");  
    };
};
```

When I create a mapObject on the server and call initialize(), it prints "hi" on the console. When I send the same object to the client and try to call it's initialize() function, I get an error saying initialize is not a function. I am transferring objects between client and server using socket.io. Both client and server can access the above code, that's what the exports is for. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Functions cannot be serialised (thankfully).

Comment: `When I send the same object to the client...` - what does this mean?

Comment: Afaik, socket.io uses JSON, and JSON does not support any serialisation of functions.

Comment: "*Both client and server can access the above code*" - Notice that each of them has its own copy of the code, executed in a different environment. They cannot share any references, any data exchange requires serialisation.

Comment: @Adam it means I instantiate the object on the server, then pass that instance to the client. Sorry I wasn't more clear.

Comment: @Bergi are you saying if the client can't access that code, then it will be able to call the function like I want?

Comment: You can send JSON objects to the client from the server, but you can't send methods (as others have mentioned, functions cannot be serialized), scopes have been lost at the point of serialization anyway, so this is why it can't be done.

Comment: @Adam okay thanks for answering

Comment: @iPodwithnomusic The client only receives strings, not objects or callable functions. When if can access the source code of that class, it can instantiate its own object, with the desired methods, and initialise it with the received data (x, y, z, spritename).